# Segmentation fault when dividing string using malloc

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, ncurses, strtok

I am using ncurses to create my own terminal. I get the string and save it in a 2D array, buffer[80][256]. I get the string using getstr(buffer[i]). Then I have the following in the main function;

```
while (strcmp(buffer[i],"exit")!=0) {
    strcpy(command,buffer[i]);
    printw("%s\n",command);

    //calls the function commands found in another source file
    commands(buffer[i]);
    mvwin(childwin, y, x);
    wnoutrefresh(childwin);
    i++;
    printw("%s",prompt);
    getstr(buffer[i]);
    doupdate();
}

//source file where one finds commands;
//global array
char*final[40];

void commands (char input[]){
  char **buffer =split(input);

...
}

//creating segmentation fault
char **split(char input[]){
  char *ptr;
  int i=0;

  ptr = strtok(input," ");

  while(split != NULL){
    final[i] = malloc(strlen(ptr)+1);
    strcpy(final[i],ptr);
    ptr = strtok(NULL," ");
    i++;
  }
 return final;
}
```

What the above function is doing; it is receiving the input by the user buffer[i] and it is dividing the strings into separate elements within array buffer in function commands. e.g. if the user enters print hello my name is, buffer in function commands with hold; buffer[0] = print, buffer[1] = hello buffer[2] = my ....

From my testing it seems like the malloc is the thing causing it, but I have no idea on how to solve it.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: what do you think this line is doing? `while(split != NULL){`  perhaps you meant: `while(ptr != NULL){`

Comment: the variable `final[]` is not defined within the posted code.  How many pointers are defined?  what happens if the 'input` contains more entries than are allowed for in the definition of `final[]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
 while(split != NULL){
```

Instead of check `split` for `NULL` you need to check if `ptr` is `NULL`.

If it is `NULL` then your `malloc` will allocate `1` byte and memory's dereference will cause problems due to overflow.

Comment: @lfarr  Glad if it helped.